# Не удается связать цикл while php и java script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

есть ссылки на потоки m3u8, по некоторым блокируют политикой CORS.
не получается связать цикл while php и javascript

это код с AJAX

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<?
include "conect.php";
$uno = 0;
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table 1`");
while ($result_k=$result->fetch_assoc()):
++$uno;
$name = $result_k['name'];
$url = $result_k['url'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
    var xhr = new XHR();
    xhr.open('GET', '<? echo $url ?>', true);
    xhr.onerror = function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "hls.php", //Путь к обработчику
    data: ({name:" <?echo $name?>"}),
    dataType: "html"
    });
    }
    xhr.send();
</script>
<?
echo $uno."_".$name."<br>";
endwhile;
?>
```

это код обработчика php

```
<?
include "conect.php";
if (!$_POST["name"] == NULL) {
$name = $_POST["name"];
$db->query("DELETE FROM `table 1` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
};
?>
```

Comment: а зачем в этом коде нужен javascript? Всё можно сделать на православном php

Comment: как с помощью PHP проверить XMLHttpRequest заголовок на блокировку политикой CORS, если ссылку проверять через get_headers, то в ответе всегда будет присутствовать Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, но как только в тело идет JS то начинаются проблемы, если знаете решение то пишите, мне не нужны пустые слова.

Comment: Кроме `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` в ответе ещё имеются заголовки, относящиеся к CORS, но вы их, конечно, игнорируете. Сделайте запрос как положено и будет вам счастье

Comment: в ответе ещё имеются заголовки, относящиеся к CORS? Что за такие заголовки